# jquery slideUp/slideDown cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have an open div on my site, a welcome message, which has a `slideUp`/`slideDown` toggle, so the user can click 'Close' and it slides up the div. However, everytime you land on this page, it's open... and I'd like to apply a cookie to this so if the user presses the `slideUp` toggle, it adds a cookie and keeps it at `display:none`.

Here is my jQuery code so far... and I'm hoping to use the [cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin which might make things easier?

```
var welcome_active = false;
$('.welcome-container .trigger span').click(function() {
    if (!welcome_active) {
        $('.welcome-container .content').slideUp('slow', function() {});
        $(this).find('span').removeClass('ss-navigatedown');
        $(this).find('em').html('About');
        $(this).find('span').addClass('ss-navigateup');
        welcome_active = true;
        console.log('test');
    } else {
        $('.welcome-container .content').slideDown('slow', function() {});
        $(this).find('span').removeClass('ss-navigateup');
        $(this).find('em').html('Close');
        $(this).find('span').addClass('ss-navigatedown');
        welcome_active = false;
    }
});
```

Any ideas if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: That's answering your question. Now you have to show where you are stuck if you want more specific help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this, using the cookie plugin you mentioned, but you can also use local storage if you don't have to support older browsers:

```
var welcome_active = false;
if($.cookie('welcome_active')=='1'){
  $('.welcome-container .content').slideUp('slow', function() {});
  $(this).find('span').removeClass('ss-navigatedown');
  $(this).find('em').html('About');
  $(this).find('span').addClass('ss-navigateup');
  welcome_active = true;
}
$('.welcome-container .trigger span').click(function() {
  if (!welcome_active) {
    $('.welcome-container .content').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $(this).find('span').removeClass('ss-navigatedown');
    $(this).find('em').html('About');
    $(this).find('span').addClass('ss-navigateup');
    welcome_active = true;
    console.log('test');
    $.cookie('welcome_active', '1', { expires: 7 });
  } else {
    $('.welcome-container .content').slideDown('slow', function() {});
    $(this).find('span').removeClass('ss-navigateup');
    $(this).find('em').html('Close');
    $(this).find('span').addClass('ss-navigatedown');
    welcome_active = false;
    $.cookie('welcome_active', '0', { expires: 7 });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cookie simply by editing document.cookie

ex :

```
document.cookie="slideState=up";
```

Next you just have to read document.cookie and parse the string to get your value.

I suggest you to use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) it's simple and efficient and it has a very good [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage)